# How can I edit lines containing M values with the ArcGIS JS API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am working with the ArcGIS JavaScript API and want to move and edit the vertices of a polyline analog to the following sample: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/ed/ed_toolbar.html

This works fine as long as the polyline does not contain M Values. If it does contain M Values I get the following error in firebug. 
Errorcode:-2147221399, description: „Geometry does not have M Value(s), hence cannot update the feature."

What am I doing wrong?

Here’s my code:

```
function initEditing(layers) {
    var myMap = this;
    var firePerimeterFL = myMap.getLayer("firePerimeterFL");

    var editToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Edit(myMap);
    dojo.connect(editToolbar, "onDeactivate", function(tool,graphic,info) {
      if(info.isModified){
        firePerimeterFL.applyEdits(null, [graphic], null);
      }
    });

    var editingEnabled = false;
    dojo.connect(firePerimeterFL, "onDblClick", function(evt) {
      dojo.stopEvent(evt);
      if (editingEnabled === false) {
        editingEnabled = true;
        editToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Edit.EDIT_VERTICES , evt.graphic);
      } else {
        editToolbar.deactivate();
        editingEnabled = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Editing feature geometries with M values is not supported via REST (or SOAP for that matter) at 10.0. It is a planned feature for 10.1 (along with Z values). Here's the documentation for this:  [Authoring feature services](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//009300000021000000)

Specifically:

> If you have data that has m-values, these features can be deleted, new
>   features can be inserted and the attributes of existing features can
>   be edited, but the geometry cannot be edited. All new features will
>   have their m-values set to NaN when inserted through the REST and SOAP
>   endpoints. If features with m-values are edited through the feature
>   service in ArcMap with the local editing commands, all editing
>   operations are supported.